# three divs in header, one left, one dynamic, one right

Tags: css, html, dynamic

I have a problem concerning three divs in the header of my website: http://www.pianoson.nl.

What I want:

The middlemenu needs to fill up the space between the left and the right menu. When you make the browser smaller, only the middle-menu should get smaller too.

The middle menu needs to have a minimum width, so the text in it does not get messed up.

At the moment the rightmenu drops down below the leftmenu at some point, but the three menu's should always stay together in the top.

I hope this is possible with css/html.

Thanks in advance!

The html-page:

```
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="leftmenu">
            <a href="http://www.pianoson.nl">
                <div class="key white"ID="home">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/home_32.png"></img>
                </div></a>

            <div class="key black"ID="Csharp"></div>

            <a href="http://www.pianoson.nl/genres.htm">
                <div class="key white"ID="repertoire">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/music2_32.png"></img>
                </div></a>

            <div class="key black"ID="Dsharp"></div>

            <a href="http://www.pianoson.nl/samples.htm">
                <div class="key white "ID="samples">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/music_32.png"></img>
                </div></a></div>

        <div ID="middlemenu"></div>

        <div id="rightmenu">

            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/e/fpf/184174635">
                <div class="key white "ID="linkedin">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/linkedin_32.png"></img>
                </div></a>

            <div class="key black"ID="Csharp"></div>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.comthijs.waleson">
                <div class="key white"ID="facebook">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/facebook_32.png"></img>
                </div></a>

            <div class="key black"ID="Dsharp"></div>

            <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/112443072032497378793/">
                <div class="key white "ID="googleplus">
                    <img src="http://www.pianoson.nl/images/google_32.png"></img>
                </div></a></div>
    </div>
```

And the css page:

```
body {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
width: auto;
overflow: hidden;}

div {
display: inline-block;}

#middlemenu {
height: 230px;
float: none;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
position: relative;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1;}

.key {
    float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
position: relative;
    text-align:center;}

.white {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 230px;
width: 40px;
z-index: 2;}

.black {
background-color: #000000;
height:150px;
width: 24px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right: -15px;}

.white:hover { 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 345px;
width: 60px;
z-index: 1;}

.key:hover img {
position: static;
vertical-align: -335px;
bottom: 5px;
padding: 14px;}

#menu{
width: 100%;
display: inline;
position: relative;}

#leftmenu{
float: left;}

#rightmenu{
float: right;}

div a div img{
vertical-align: -210px;
position: static;
bottom:5px; 
color: #000000;}
```

Comment: "the browser should slide over the rightmenu" - what does this mean? What's the effect you're going for?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. What do you exactly want here, Mr. Pianist? :)

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for my complicated way of describing, I find it hard to find the right words..

Comment: Is the middle menu ever going to be populated with content or is it just there for filler to separate the two left and right menus?

Comment: The middle menu will have my name and profession(pianist) and/or area that I work in ;) Indeed, it also functions as filler, which doesn't work yet either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you are looking for..

modify the css to this

```
body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
}
#middlemenu {
    height: 230px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    margin-right: 130px;
    min-width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#leftmenu {
    float: left;
}
#rightmenu {
    float: right;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
div a div img {
    vertical-align: -210px;
    position: static;
    bottom:5px;
    color: #000000;
}
.key {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.white {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 230px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.black {
    background-color: #000000;
    height:150px;
    width: 24px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.white:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 345px;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.key:hover img {
    position: static;
    vertical-align: -335px;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding: 14px;
}
```